# Storing a type in C++

Tags: c++, casting, types

Is it possible to store a type name as a C++ variable? For example, like this:

```
type my_type = int; // or string, or Foo, or any other type
void* data = ...;
my_type* a = (my_type*) data;
```

I know that 99.9% of the time there's a better way to do what you want without resorting to casting void pointers, but I'm curious if C++ allows this sort of thing.

Comment: It's not possible as written. Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve, it may be possible with templates though. Can you give us a bit more context of what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: In c++0x that specific function is possible, but there's never a place it is useful because the type information is lost when the original variable is.

Comment: The only thing I can think of to store types polymorphicaly in C++ would be _type erasure_.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, this is not possible in C++.

The RTTI `typeid` operator allows you to get some information about types at runtime: you can get the type's name and check whether it is equal to another type, but that's about it.

Comment: The name isn't portable, though.

Comment: It is portable, just not between compilers. An application compiled with GCC on linux will have the same type names as GCC on windows, but not the same as the VS compiler.

Comment: @Thomas Is this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info the operator you're talking about? This isn't an operator, right? But rather a class that stores the result of typeid()?

Comment: Fail on my part. It's [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid). Editing... (11 upvotes without anyone mentioning this glaring mistake), thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 27):

Not as written, but you could do something similar...

```
class Type
{
    public:
        virtual ~Type(){}
        virtual void* allocate()const=0;
        virtual void* cast(void* obj)const=0;
};

template<typename T> class TypeImpl : public Type
{
      public:
         virtual void* allocate()const{ return new T; }
         virtual void* cast(void* obj)const{ return static_cast<T*>(obj); }
};

// ...
Type* type = new TypeImpl<int>;
void* myint = type->allocate();
// ...
```

This kind of thing can be extended depending on what features you need.

Comment: Hi Micheal. I'm almost there with your snippet. The cast function in the derived class returns a void pointer in your code. How do I get the T* as desired?

Comment: You can explicitly in the caller if you know that the object is of the correct type. However, the reflective API that operates on any type can't reasonably have strongly-typed methods; the methods for the general type representation would need to operate on weakly-typed objects (void* in conjunction with some record of the type).

Comment: What does method `cast` achieve here? It only returns a `void*` pointer which has to be explicitly `static_cast<T*>` to a specific class before it can be used.

Answer (score 13):

You can't do that in C++, but you can use the boost any library then test for the type it holds. Example:

```
bool is_int(const boost::any & operand)
{
  return operand.type() == typeid(int);
}
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/any/s02.html

Comment: Cool, I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Boost isn't magic, if they can do it in C++, you can do it in C++, it just probably isn't easy.

Answer (score 9):

No you can't store the type directly as you want, but you can instead store the name of the type.

```
const char* str = typeid(int).name();
```

I guess whenever you planned to use that variable for comparison, you could instead at that time compare the `str` variable against the `name()` of the types.

```
const char* myType = typeid(int).name();

//....

//Some time later:
if(!strcmp(myType, typeid(int).name()))
{
  //Do something
}
```

[More info available here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)

Comment: Except that name() isn't guaranteed to be the same across platforms!

Comment: @Michael: I did not suggest saving it to a file

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you code it yourself.

```
enum Foo_Type{
    AFOO,
    B_AFOO,
    C_AFOO,
    RUN
};

struct MyFoo{
    Foo_Type m_type;
    Boost::shared_ptr<Foo> m_foo;
}
```

as commented below, what I left out was that all these "foo" types would have to be related to Foo.  Foo would, in essence, be your interface.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no guarentee that ’shared_pointer<Foo>’ is large enough to store all those different types unless ’Foo’ is related to them in some way. Also, ’_AFOO’ is an illegal identifier.

Comment: duly noted and fixed.  I'll add comments about "Foo"

Comment: You don't need `Foo` at all, you can just do `boost::shared_ptr<void>`, with appropriate deleters.

Answer (score 3):

Today I had a similar problem while coding:
I had the need to store a polymoriphic data type (here named refobj) over wich call functions of the concrete classes implementing it. I need a solution that doesn't cast the variable explicitly because I need to reduce the amount of code.

My solution (but I haven't tested it yet) looks similar to a previous answer. Actually is quite an experimental solution. It look like this...

```
// interface to use in the function

class Type   
{
public:
    virtual void* getObj()const=0;
};

// here the static_cast with the "stored" type

template<typename T> class TypeImpl : public Type
{
public:
    TypeImpl(T *obj) {myobj=obj;}
    virtual void* getObj()const{ return static_cast<T*>(myobj); }

private: 
    T* myobj;
};

// here the type that will contain the polimorific type
// that I don't want to cast explicitly in my code
Type *refobj;

// here the "user code "
void userofTypes()
{
    ( refobj->getObj() ).c_str(); 
    // getObj() should return a string type over which
    // calling string concrete functions ...let's try!
}

void main()
{
    refobj=new TypeImpl < string > ( new string("hello") );
    userofTypes();
}
// it might seem absurd don't cast refobj explicitly, but of
// course there are situation in which it can be useful!
```

Answer (score 1):

Types are not objects in C++ (where they are in Ruby, for instance), so you cannot store instances of a type. Actually, types never appear in the executing code (RTTI is just extra storage).

Based on your example, it looks like you're looking for typedefs.

```
typedef int Number;
Number one = 1;
Number* best = (Number*) one;
```

Note that a typedef isn't *storing* the type; it is *aliasing* the type.

Comment: `Number` isn't a variable, i.e., it's meaning can't be changed at run-time.

Comment: Noted. Based on his example, though, I don't think he's actually looking for storage.

Comment: You're right that my example isn't doing anything a typedef can't do, but I would have ultimately liked to store the type (as a member of a class, say). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A better way could be to do `using Number = int;`

Answer (score 1):

A better process is to have a common base class containing a load method, and an interface for *loaders*.  This would allow other parts of the program to load data generically without knowledge of the descendant class:

```
struct Load_Interface;

struct Loader
{
  virtual void visit(Load_Interface&) = 0;
}

struct Load_Interface
{
  virtual void accept_loader(Loader& l)
    {
        l.visit(*this);
    }
};
```

This design avoids the need to know the types of objects.